# Displaying only the negative or positive contours?(not labels)

Tags: qgis

I have a coastal environment and I would like to hide land contours and keep isobaths only(and vice versa probably). One solution would be to superimpose the land polygon, but I do not want to do that. What is the expression I must use in QGIS 3.10?

Additionally dew to very steep bottom slopes isobaths are very dense in some spots and the result is not good. How do I loosen up a little? Any ideas? 
[image]

Comment: You can filter your data https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VKLoGbQ056Q.

Comment: Thanks Kadir. I used "ELEV" > 0 and it worked. I thought I should work with attribute table and query builder. For the density of contours I used the interval in Raster>Extraction>Interval.

Comment: you can add this as an answer and then accept it to help people in the future who have the same question